# AWS redshift schedule for specific days using CRON

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to set up Redshift scheduling using CRON for running it 5 days a week (MON-FRI) between 7-14 ETC. The format is described as such:

```
Cron format: minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week year 
Use , (comma) to include additional values, - (hyphen) to specify a range, * (asterisk) to include all values, and / (forward slash) to specify increments.
```

So I use these values:

Pause - `0 16 * * 1-5 *`
Start - `0 9 * * 1-5 *`

AWS shows me an error `Invalid cron schedule expression: cron(0 9 * * 1-5 *)`. If I substitute `1-5` by `?`, it works, but that's not what I need.

Is the range indeed supported by this scheduler and I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third asterisk has to be a question mark when specifying the day of the week like this: `0 16 ? * 1-5 *`

The [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) says:

> The * (asterisk) wildcard includes all values in the field. In the
> Hours field, * would include every hour. You cannot use * in both the
> Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields. If you use it in one, you must
> use ? in the other.